# Beginnings of an SPA login system

Tags: php, jquery, html, authentication, single-page-application

I am trying to implement a simple login system with php/mysql/jquery. I want it to be a single page app, so I have this for my "index.php":

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>it IT</title>
<script src="reqscripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this for my jquery:

js/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").load("templates/indexforms.php");

    $("#login").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("checklogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function(){
            $("#main").load("templates/login_success.php");
            $("#login").remove();
            $("#register").remove();
        });
    });
});
```

This form gets loaded (templates/indexforms.php):

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<form id="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <h1>Member Login</h1>
    <p>Username:<input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></p>
    <p>Password:<input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Right now, when I try to login - it gets stuck on `localhost/~Eamon/checklogin.php` (which doesn't have any html in it) and a completely blank page is rendered (no source code at all). Do I need to include application .js in my indexforms.php template? Where would I do this? Also, if you look at my jquery, I am loading the forms right after the DOM is ready - but on form submission...the forms are supposed to be removed - and the login_success.php should be loaded.

**UPDATE**

checklogin.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="xxx"; // Mysql username
$password="xxx"; // Mysql password
$db_name="itit"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$mysqli = new mysqli("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

$sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username=? and password=?");
$sql->bind_param('ss',$myusername,$mypassword);
$sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();//apply to prepare statement
$numRows = $sql->num_rows;

if($numRows === 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

I don't think my javascript file is being loaded. I put `alert("here")` before e.preventDefault and nothing happens...is the second line of my application.js file messing things up? Why is it not getting loaded?

I found this here - does this help anyone?

> JavaScript files loaded using the script tag are blocking by nature. Everything that’s happening or loading on the page is halted while the script is downloaded and executed. And remember that this applies to each script tag. Some modern browsers may let you download these in parallel, but the rest of the page is still blocked from doing anything meaningful

**UPDATE**

I put `echo "success"` inside the if block of checklogin.php...like this (at the bottom):

```
...

if($numRows === 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
    echo "success";
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

and it never gets there. If I put it just before the if statement it displays the echo message...which means that the user isnt being found in my database...or something like that?

**UPDATE**

Put `var_dump($numRows)` after `$numRows = $sql->num_rows;` like this:

```
...

$numRows = $sql->num_rows;
var_dump($numRows);

if($numRows === 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
}
...
```

I get int(1) as response...

**UPDATE**

Change the if condition in checklogin.php:

```
if($numRows === "int(1)"){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    session_destroy();
}
```

The else block gets executed and I see "Wrong Username or Password" - as I should.

**UPDATE**

Changed jquery code to this...still no luck:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").load("templates/indexforms.php", function () {
        $("#login").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("checklogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function() {
                $("#main").load("templates/login_success.php");
                $("#login").remove();
                $("#register").remove();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**CORRECTION**

The above code is correct! I just needed to restart the server! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Found a new problem, here you go: [simple login system spa/php/mysql/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157901/simple-login-system-spa-php-mysql-jquery)

Comment: Placement of PHP and HTML is important. Are you placing any output before PHP? I.e.: HTML, whitespace etc.

Comment: Also if possible, can you show us what is inside `checklogin.php`? Omitting any vital information of course.

Comment: @Fred hey...i will update my question with checklogin.php...and i dont think I am outputting anything (like echo?) unless the login fails.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any `echos` mixed in with `header` stuff. Do you have error reporting set to `on` to see if there are in fact any errors?

Comment: Safest way to build, is PHP, then HTML. That way, if you have any header information, it needs to be placed before any output, including `echos`.

Comment: Modify your edit to remove and replace username and password with generic information. You have yours posted, not safe. Generic meaning, `username=myusername` and `password=mypassword`.

Comment: What's in your `index.php`? That I need to see what kind of structure you have. Calls to files, etc.

Comment: @Fred the only echo i have is in the else statement at the bottom of checklogin.php - which isnt being executed because I know I am typing in the correct member username and password (as i created it in the mysql database). thanks for the password thing...and i posted my index.php...it is the first block of code in my question

Comment: @Fred do i need session_start() in my indexforms.php?

Comment: Try adding `<?php session_start(); ?>` above `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your index.php file.

Comment: Yes, you need `session_start();` in every .php file involved, and it needs to be on top, as you have it in your others right now. See my above comment about adding it to your index.php

Comment: If you don't have any PHP tags already set for `indexforms.php`, then you'll need to put `<?php session_start; ?>` on top of the forms code.

Comment: @Fred ..tried your suggestion - still no luck - i added session_start to the indexforms.php too - should i do that?

Comment: @Fred we must have posted at the same time...didnt see your comment about the indexforms...funny i had that question. where would i have php tags?

Comment: Just do `<?php session_start(); ?><form id="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">... rest of form`

Comment: @Fred tried it...no luck

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31843/discussion-between-ewizard-and-fred)

Comment: When you fire up the whole thing, does the form show up?

Comment: I'd also recommend to use more than just jquery for a spa

Comment: @user1737909   what else should i use? im trying to avoid using any frameworks (like backbone or node) as I am still learning the in's and out's of the languages

Comment: yeah, that's a valid point, but i'm afraid you're going to have a code spaghetti. But if you want to train, that still can fits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the JavaScript to this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $("#main").load("templates/indexforms.php", function ()
  {

    $("#login").submit(function(e)
    {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.post("checklogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function()
      {
        $("#main").load("templates/login_success.php");
        $("#login").remove();
        $("#register").remove();
      });

    }
    )

  }
  )

}
)
```

Notice that the script waits until `indexforms.php` is loaded in `#main` before adding the submit event to `#login` (at the moment it's trying to do it (pretty much) at the same time so `$("#login").submit(...` is run before there is any `#login` element).

Comment: i updated my question to show you what I did...I wasn't sure how your brackets were working...im not sure if i got it or not...let me know if there are any syntax errors