# simple login system spa/php/mysql/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, authentication, single-page-application

I am trying to create a simple login system - I have gotten as far as my user being able to sign in and see his profile page. I am trying to make the link work in the login_success.php template...right now it just appends "#" to the url (because I am using that as a place holder.

Here is my code:

js/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main").load("templates/indexforms.php", function () {
        $("#login").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("checklogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function() {
                $("#main").load("templates/login_success.php");
                $("#login").remove();
                $("#register").remove();
            });
        });

        $("#register").submit(function(e) {  
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("checkreglogin.php", $(this).serialize(), function(){
                $("#main").load("templates/login_success.php");
                $("#login").remove();
                $("#register").remove();
            });
        });
    });


    $("#loginlinkdiv a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#main").empty();
        $("#main").load("templates/logout.php");
    });

    $("#logoutlinkdiv a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#main").empty();
        $("#main").load("templates/indexforms.php");
    });
});
```

templates/login_success.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'] === null){
    header("location: ../index.php");
}
?>

<h1>Login Successful</h1>
<h2>Username: <? echo $_SESSION['username']?></h2>
<div id="logoutlinkdiv" >
    <a href = "#" >Log out</a>
</div>
```

I can't figure out why nothing happens when I click the log out link.

Comment: It should work. Try putting your JS at the bottom of the page instead of the top. Try putting an alert("hi") in the logout div to see if its not your indexforms.php that crashes when called from that page.

Comment: If page/content (login_sucess) is loaded via ajax -> maybe script doesn't recognize it as part of DOM, so, try to use on: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @MrJack I did as you said...nothing happens still...even with code at bottom...i put alert(hi) in the logout link div and it gets rendered in the browser correctly.

Comment: @nevermind tried this `$("#loginlinkdiv a").on("click", function(event) {`     still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this should work:

```
$(document).on("click", "#logoutlinkdiv a", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
   alert('logout button clicked');
 });
```

And explanation: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11203

Comment: Anchor to `#main` instead of document.

Comment: @nevermind did it...thanks - why did this work and not the other way?

Comment: Please check this (more detailed explanation than on previous link i have sent): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on/8111096#8111096.